# How can I obtain data from consecutive URLs

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have consecutive Url's up to page number when I try to execute in a loop it does not work here is my code I want to get data from different URLs up to page number

```
for(var i = 1 ; i < 50; i ++)
{
    var pageNumber = 1
    var urlPath = "https://api.blabla.com/blabla?page=\(pageNumber)"
    var url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { data,response,error  -> Void in
        if(error == nil)
        {
            //JSON Parse
        }
    })
    task.resume()
    pageNumber++
}
```

When I do this it works for `pageNumber = 1` but the problem is that it gives the same Url each time, basicly when I write `println(url!)` in `//JSON Parse`.
Every time it gives me:

```
api.blabla.com.blabla?page=1
```

So I checked that data does not nil but it only works for `pagenumber = 1`

Comment: Define "does not work". Have you checked to make sure that `error` was really `nil`? After you're done parsing the JSON, do you update the UI according, dispatching that back to the main queue?

Comment: Can you provide more data on the issue? What is the console saying? Are ```data``` and ```response``` objects empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `pageNumber` to 1 every time the loop starts anew. Get rid of that variable altogether and just use `i`.

Comment: Oh you are right it is the most silly mistake I have ever done. Thank you so much :)